# Pass dynamic value to url in Postman

Tags: postman

I have 2 requests

## 1st Request

After did my first request, I get the response where I can parse for a taskId

In my test tab, I will then parse and store it like this

```
let taskId = pm.response.json().body.result[0].data.task
console.log(taskId)
```

I can see taskId printing in my console as `938`

## 2nd Request

I require making a GET with this dynamic URL with the `taskId` that I got from the first one

```
http://localhost:3000/fortinet/monitor/{{taskId}}
```

So I set the above URL , set the HTTP verb to `GET`

in my Pre-request Script tab, I did this

```
let taskId = pm.globals.get("taskId")
```

## Result

> ReferenceError: taskId is not defined

Image Result

[image]

How can I debug this further?

Comment: All of the questions that you seem to be asking lately can be solved by just reading the Postman documentation. It seems like a waste of effort to write out the questions, in my opinion.

Comment: I don’t agree. I asked legit question. I delete the one that I think is unless. I left the one that I think is good.

Comment: I’ve read a few questions now and the responses are basically people pointing you to the Postman documentation. The answer to this question highlighted this again. It’s not a problem but the ethos of SO requires some level of research and attempts to solve the issues first, I don’t see this in your questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set variable, but you are doing it wrong. 
try this: 

`pm.globals.set("taskID", pm.response.json().body.result[0].data.task)`

more you can read here:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/

Answer (score 15):

The most suggested way is to use :key as in

```
http://localhost:3000/fortinet/monitor/:taskId
```

See the colon before **taskId**. The reason being, URI values sometimes many not be environment dependent. So, based on the usecase, you can use  like I said or {{taskId}}

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that URL which ends with resource identified like `https://example.com/:pathVariable.xml` or `https://example.com/:pathVariable.json` will not work.

You can go with `https://example.com/:pathVariable` with `Accept: application/json` header.

Answer (score 0):

For passing dynamic value, first you have to set it in environment or global variable in **`Tests` tab** because tests runs after request and you will get response value after request sent, but because you get response in json you have to first parse it, so what you can write in `Tests` tab is as follows:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("taskId", jsonData.token); // OR
postman.setGlobalVariable("taskId", jsonData.token);
```

Then you can use `taskId` as `{{taskId}}` wherever you want in url parameters or in request body or form data wherever.

If you want to know in detail how to extract data from response and chain it to request then you can go to [this postman's official blog post](https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/) which is written by Abhinav Asthana CEO and Co Founder of Postman Company.